# How do i make an image monochrome in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Let's say i have an icon in grey scale, and now I want to change it into a certain green tone instead. The icon is anti-aliased around the edges, so it doesn't look too rugged, and I want to keep this anti-aliasing, but now in a green scale.

Basically I want to define that what was black should now be a specific green, and every lighter shade of grey should be an equally lighter shade of green.

[Like the scale shown here, I'd like to change the scale of an image from [black to white] to [green to white]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nerl4.jpg)

How is this possible i Photoshop? Am I right, that this could be called a monochrome image?

**Solved**

It seems that "Gradient Map" does exactly this. `Image -> Adjustments -> Gradient Map`.

[Here I've applied a Gradient Map Adjustment Layer to the grey scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2dNW.jpg)

Comment: A cautionary note: this technique will not produce a true monotone in the printing press sense, i.e. an image that can be reproduced with a single coloured ink. But that is one for another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradient Map Adjustment Layers are awesome, precise and exactly what you're after.

Gradient Maps map the underlying image's brightness to a point on the gradient. This means you can choose exact colours for highlights, midtones and shadows.

[image: Gradient Map Adjustment Layer]

Do I love Gradient Map Adjustment Layers? YES. There's many ways to do something like this in Photoshop, but none are as easy or precise as a Gradient Map.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm add a layer style with either a gradient or color overlay

Comment: While that will change the color tone of the icon, I find i hard to control the exact color scale that this produces.